# How can I see the edit suggestions I made?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I would like to see a list of edit suggestions I made to questions and answers by other users.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/379894/nevermind9?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

Comment: @Rene Thanks, I had not seen it. +1.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Just noticed you edited a bunch of recently-closed questions. **Please do not edit these questions within five days of closure.** This creates extra work for reopen-reviewers and deprives the post author of their one chance to get their post reopened, should they choose. Please wait until five days after closure before editing these posts. (Otherwise, I appreciate your work!)